# How to refresh Custom ListView item from database using button in ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-arrayadapter

How can I refresh the items displayed in the `ListView` using a button in the `ArrayAdapter`. The items displayed in the `ListView` is coming from mysql database. What I want to happen is that every time I press a `Button` inside the `ArrayAdapter` the data in the `Arraylist` will be refreshed, as well as the displayed items in the `ListView`. I'm trying to make something like the `SwipeRefreshLayout`, but with the use of the `Button`.

Why I want to do this is because when a button is clicked it updates my database, and removes/updates(Button.setText) the item from my list.

Button in ArrayAdapter:

```
if(orderList.getStatusID() == 1)    {
viewHolder.btnStatus.setText("Press if Ready");
viewHolder.btnStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://" + IPvariable.IP + "/myDB/update_order_ready.php",
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                if(response.contains("success")){
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Order Sent", Toast.LENGTH.SHORT).show();
                                    //ADD Code to Refresh List
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Order Sending Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("order_id", String.valueOf(orderList.getOrder_id()));
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

            }
        });

}
```